# Upload any DateTime from CSV in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am uploading CSVs in a django project but it shows error from laptop to laptop.

**Models.py**

```
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.date.today)
```

**views.py**

```
csv_file = request.FILES['file']
data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)

uploaded_by = request.user

for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
    _, created = ItemBatch.objects.update_or_create(name=column[0], pid=column[1], quantity=column[2],date=column[8])
```

The problem is that it takes only this format :

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
```

I updated **settings.py** with this:

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     
'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',     
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        
'%Y-%m-%d',              
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        
'%m/%d/%Y',              
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        
'%m/%d/%y',
'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M' 
]




LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = False
```

error:

> ["'10-7-2019 12:00' value has an invalid format. It must be in
>   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

What changes do I need to make such that it accepts every datetime format?

**EDIT**
as per rudraa's suggestion I defined my formats in the CustomManager function:

```
def get_date_value(self, value):
    FORMATS = [
        '%d-%m-%y %H:%M',
        '%d-%y-%m %H:%M',
        '%m-%d-%y %H:%M',
        '%m-%y-%d %H:%M',
        '%y-%m-%d %H:%M',
        '%y-%d-%m %H:%M',
        '%d/%m/%y %H:%M',
        '%d/%y/%m %H:%M',
        '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
        '%m/%y/%d %H:%M',
        '%y/%m/%d %H:%M',
        '%y/%d/%m %H:%M'
    ]
    input_formats = FORMATS
```

But while uploading the file with `15/7/2019 18:30` format i.e '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M' it says:

> redefinition of group name 'd' as group 6; was group 1 at position 133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` is being used in [**`django forms`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/54b331451cb22ee354beadf31ee42cbd714877f0/django/forms/fields.py#L438) only. It will validate any date given in formats with `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`. But when you are using the model directly to store the data, it will only accept data if its given in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`. It evaluates the datetime string against this [**`regex`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/42b9a23267f14be39b9b00958e18d5746783208e/django/utils/dateparse.py#L22). So I would recommend to write a [**`custom manager`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance) to convert the values to `datetime` format, and use it to create/update the value. For example:

```
from django.utils import formats


class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def custom_update_or_create(self,*args, **kwargs):
        date_time_value = kwargs.pop('date', None)
        if date_time_value:
            kwargs['date'] = self.get_date_value(date_time_value)
        return super(CustomManager, self).update_or_create(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_date_value(self, value):
         input_formats = [
            '%d-%m-%y %H:%M',
            '%d-%y-%m %H:%M',
            '%m-%d-%y %H:%M',
            '%m-%y-%d %H:%M',
            '%y-%m-%d %H:%M',
            '%y-%d-%m %H:%M',
            '%d/%m/%y %H:%M',
            '%d/%y/%m %H:%M',
            '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
            '%m/%y/%d %H:%M',
            '%y/%m/%d %H:%M',
            '%y/%d/%m %H:%M'
         ]

         for format in input_formats:
            try:
                return self.strptime(value, format)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                continue

    def strptime(self, value, format):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, format)
```

And Use it in the model:

```
class ItemBatch(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.date.today)
    # rest of the fields
    objects = CustomManager()
```

Finally use that method to create/update new instances:

```
ItemBatch.objects.custom_update_or_create(name=column[0], pid=column[1], quantity=column[2],date=column[8])
```

Comment: I have to put this CustomManager in models.py ? and also in my model ItemBatch instead of `date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.date.today)` I have to write`date =  CustomManager()` ?

Comment: not instead, you need to put both. Please see my updated answer

Comment: I tried that and it works like a charm but Can I check which formats I can upload or does it work with all the formats ?

Comment: I uploaded the file with `15-07-2019 18:30` a null entry is passed in the table

Comment: Instead of importing the formats like this `input_formats = formats.get_format_lazy('DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS')` Can I specify the formats in CustomManager itself ?

Comment: yes, you can. Also, I am checking why you are getting the null values

Comment: I updated the question with one more query, please see EDIT

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add following in settings.py:

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
'%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
'%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
'%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
]
```

Comment: I did but it still says `["'10-7-2019 12:00' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]`

Comment: By default USE_L10N is True, which will ignore custom datetime format settings, please add USE_L10N=False, in settings.py

Comment: Also if you would like to disable timezone support, add USE_TZ = False

Comment: I have update the question with my settings.py and I already have `USE_L10N=False` and `USE_TZ = False`